# Problem in attaching two plots obtained from two different expression

Tags: plotting, graphics

```
z = 1/3;
w1 = -6.507020907706122`*^-15 Cos[11.138034591281526` x] - 
   3.620441043680715`*^-15 Cosh[11.138034591281526` x] - 
   0.7169455947178107` Sin[11.138034591281526` x] - 
   0.01904792060284493` Sinh[11.138034591281526` x];
w2 = 0.38754182303955004` Cos[11.138034591281526` (-(1/3) + x)] - 
   0.3899009885381456` Cosh[11.138034591281526` (-(1/3) + x)] - 
   0.17709039562013243` Sin[11.138034591281526` (-(1/3) + x)] + 
   0.3899012654884649` Sinh[11.138034591281526` (-(1/3) + x)];
W = Piecewise[{{w1, x <= z}, {w2, x >= z}}]
UU = 2.51195553449907`*^-14 Cos[3.5811112720649185` y] + 
  0.005544404132968294` Sin[3.5811112720649185` y]
Plot[W, {x, 0, 1}]
Rotate[Plot[UU, {y, 0, 1}], \[Pi]/2]
```

I am getting two plots which are obtained from `W and UU`. `W` and `UU` are having a dependency on x and y respectively.`W(x=z) and UU(y=1)` takes the same value. I want to club these two plots and visualize the end results. I tried using `Show` but did not work.

[image: T joint]

Comment: `Show[Plot[W, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 ParametricPlot[{UU, y}, {y, -1, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  GridLines -> {None, {1}}], PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]`?

Comment: I am trying to plot a T shape, the horizontal line is governed by W and the vertical line is governed by UU, and x=z and y=1 is the attaching point of the horizontal line and verticle line.

Comment: This looks like a beam vibration problem. Is w[x,t] transverse vibration and u[y,t] longitudinal vibration?  If so how do you wish to plot the longitudinal vibration? Do you want this plotted as a transverse vibration?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
wplot = Plot[W, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red];
uuplot = Plot[UU, {y, 0, 1}];

Show[MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, TranslationTransform[{0, 1}]] &, wplot, 1], 
 MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, Composition[TranslationTransform[{z + (W /. x->z), 0}],
     RotationTransform[Pi/2]]] &, uuplot, 1], 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}, GridLines -> {{-z, z}, {1}}, 
 Ticks -> {{{z, Style["z", 20]}}, {{1, Style[1, 20]}}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Show[MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, TranslationTransform[{-z - (W /. x -> z), 1}]] &, 
    wplot, 1], 
  MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[Pi/2]] &, uuplot, 1], 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1.5},  GridLines -> {{-z, z}, {1}},
 Ticks -> {{{-z, Style["-z", 20]}, {z, Style["z", 20]}}, {{1, Style[1, 20]}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: uplot is crossing the zero , the w also shifted by z. I am trying to on the verticle line to translate by z amount.